# CORS Alternatives

Tags: javascript, cors, ups

I am a very amateur programmer attempting to make a simple website to track `UPS` shipments. The basic idea is for the user to scan a UPS `tracking` number and for a certain few critical pieces of information (primarily custom shipment reference numbers) to be displayed alongside data pulled from a local file.  I am utilizing the UPS Developer `APIs` to accomplish this.

Now for my limitations.  The only browser the company allows is Internet Explorer.  The "website" I have is unfortunately no more than a page hosted on my company Microsoft `Sharepoint` site.  It can run absolutely no server side code which, to my understanding, leaves me just `javascript` to work with.  My only tool then seems to be `XHR` but `Cross Origin` rules block all my requests.  I don't ever see an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header so I assume that means `CORS` is not allowed by the `UPS` servers.  Just in case I am missing something, here is the `Http` request and response headers.

Request

```
Request OPTIONS                 /ups.app/xml/Track HTTP/1.1
Accept                          */*
Origin                          **Private but definitely not UPS's domain
Access-Control-Request-Method   OPTIONS
Access-Control-Request-Headers  content-type
Accept-Encoding                 gzip, deflate
User-Agent                      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)
Host                            www.ups.com
Content-Length                  0
DNT                             1
Connection                      Keep-Alive
Cache-Control                   no-cache
```

Response

```
Response                        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date                            Mon, 17 Aug 2015 12:32:40 GMT
Server                          Apache
X-Frame-Options                 SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length                  0
Allow                           GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Vary                            User-Agent
Keep-Alive                      timeout=65
Connection                      Keep-Alive
Content-Type                    text/html
```

Based on my research, the only option I have left is to set up a `proxy` for the `XHR`.  However, seeing as I cannot run any code on my server, I would have to set up the proxy somewhere else which I am extremely hesitant to do.  The information is not exactly sensitive but I'm not entirely sure how my IT guys would react.

Do I have any other course of action here or should I go the proxy route?

Comment: If you could bypass CORS, that would be a front-page-headline security flaw. The UPS APIs are designed to be used from a server.

Comment: If they do not support CORS for JSON, your choice is to run a proxy or do not get the response. There is nothing that can be done other than removing the security feature from the browser which is not a smart thing to do. Have you looked at the API: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have successfully done something like this already in Excel where Cross Origin is not an issue.  Using VBA and MSXML, it worked perfectly.  This is probably not possible but can javascript be used to call a VBA function stored on the company share drive?

Comment: @sir_peppiny the reason it works in excel (VBA) is because it doesn't have this security restriction like browsers do.  What you can do is create a web service on another server on the same domain and wrap the `UPS` calls in that service then call the service that is on your domain...

Comment: Sharepoint should support asp.net server side code. Double check that.